# Have a static html page in next.js project (outside of /public/-folder)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created a new next.js project. Is it possible to have an accessible static html page "outside" the project?

For example the structure would look like this:

```
.next
components
node_modules
pages
public
styles
aboutus
```

Now looking at the folder /aboutus/, it will have a structure like this:

```
css (folder)
js (folder)
images (folder)
index.html
```

Where the index.html references the css, js and the images.

But when i call http://localhost:3000/aboutus it gives me a 404 error.

Already tried this setup locally, but didn't work.
It turned out a 404 error.
I expect that to work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have an accessible static html page "outside" the project?

No. Only files that are in the pages folder are generated as pages. [pages in NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#:%7E:text=In%20Next.js%2C%20a%20page%20is%20a%20React%20Component%20exported%20from%20a%20.js%2C%20.jsx%2C%20.ts%2C%20or%20.tsx%20file%20in%20the%20pages%20directory.%20Each%20page%20is%20associated%20with%20a%20route%20based%20on%20its%20file%20name.)

The closest you can get to accomplish that is by running [`npm run export`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) and manually insert your "aboutus" folder in the "out" folder. But the project wont have the benefits of [These features](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features).

Answer (score 0):

In case the `.js` is not Next related, have you tried to put the `aboutus` folder in `public/aboutus` ?